# Remove Parenthesis from String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  x = x.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');
  y = y.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');

  x = x.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
  y = y.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
```

okay I understand that the first block removes the curly brackets, and the second block of code removes the regular brackets.  I want to remove parenthesis now.. can someone show me how?

I've gotten the above code by just googling.. but I don't understand "how" they come up with this, can someone please explain?  thanks

Comment: ah okay, i just didn't know what to look for.  thanks

Comment: Dont you care about removing only valid paranthesis?

Comment: Why don't you accept the below answer ?

Answer (score 114):

### First Regex

```
x = x.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');
y = y.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');
```

In your first regex `/[{()}]/g` the outer square brackets `[]` makes a **character class**, it will match one of the character specified inside of it. In this case the characters `{` `(` `)` `}`.

Outside of the `/regexp/` you have the `g` (global) **modifier** meaning that your entire regular expression will match as many times as it can , and it will not just make to the first match.

### Second regex

```
x = x.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
y = y.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
```

In your second regex `/[\[\]']+/g` the outer square brackets `[]` makes a **character class**, it will match one of the character specified inside of it. In this case the characters `[` `]` `'`.

Note that the square brackets appear scaped inside the **[character class]** as `\[` `\]`.

After it you have specified a `+` **quantifier**, it makes the preceding rule match `one or more` times in a row. Note that this is redundant, even if it works, this is not quite what you want.

Outside of the `/regularexpression/` you have the `g` (global) **modifier** meaning that your entire regular expression will match as many times as it can , and it will not just make to the first match.

---

### Suggested Solution

```js
run1.onclick = function() {
  //removes "(" and ")"
  output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace(/[()]/g, ''); 
}

run2.onclick = function() {
  //removes (){}[]
  output2.innerHTML = input2.value.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, ''); 
}
```

```html
<p>Remove ()</p>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="(123) 1234-1234">
<input id="run1" type="button" value="run">
<span id="output1"></span>

<hr>

<p>Remove ()[]{}</p>
<input id="input2" type="text" value="Hello (this) is [] a {{test}}!">
<input id="run2" type="button" value="run">
<span id="output2"></span>
```

Comment: I improved my answer a little, even tho it wasn't accepted it is quite visited.

Answer (score 0):

```js
run1.onclick = function() {
  //removes "(" and "), white space and -"
  // output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace(/[()]/g, '');
  output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace(/[()\ \s-]+/g, '');
}

run2.onclick = function() {
  //removes (){}[]
  output2.innerHTML = input2.value.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, ''); 
}
```

```html
<p>Remove ()</p>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="(123) 1234-1234">
<input id="run1" type="button" value="run">
<span id="output1"></span>

<hr>

<p>Remove ()[]{}</p>
<input id="input2" type="text" value="Hello (this) is [] a {{test}}!">
<input id="run2" type="button" value="run">
<span id="output2"></span>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.