# How to remove the array in a string?

Tags: javascript, angular, date

loginTime: "[2021-01-18 06:18:57.000000]";

I need this to -> "2021-01-18 06:18:57.000000";

how to remove the array and make it just string?

Comment: how to remove the [ ] sign here? It is in JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844426/11926970 Read this answer it will help you

Comment: Try `'[2021-01-18 06:18:57.000000]'.slice(1, -1)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics) as following this, you'd better call that as a 'bracket' (specifically, squared brackets)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```js
"[2021-01-18 06:18:57.000000]".replace(/\[|\]/g, '')
```

Matches the character "[" and "]", replaces them with nothing.